# Rounding Issues with Totals in SSRS

Tags: reporting-services, ssrs-2008, ssrs-2008-r2, ssrs-2012, reportingservices-2005

I have details figures like these:

```
  Sales Amount
  £285.00
  £16,249.51
  £345.68
```

But the total returned was:

```
  £16,880.18
```

while I was expecting:

```
  £16,880.19
```

This is supposed to be the sum of details but the last digit is being rounded. How do I overcome this limitation?

Answer (score 2):

Since your round your detail in the second decimal digit you can use the following expression (change the field in the expression to match your own)

```
Sum( Round(Fields!val.Value,2))
```

Another option could be rounding your dataset in your SQL code

Comment: Yea, tried that before and still getting the same error

Comment: Please provide more info like numbers before rounding

Comment: For this to work you really do have to round your detail and your total.  My guess is the detail is formatted as currency but the actual data behind it has many decimal places.  By the time you get to your sum the decimal rounds down rather than up.  Like this answer suggests, round the detail first.

Comment: Indeed the decimal part has more than 2 digits and that explains the inconsistency between detail and total. Since detail visible part is ''rounded'' due to formatting, you can apply the actual rounding at the total expression

Comment: I have a similar problem. I am displaying an average  balance for broker in a month and want to display the average for a company. 
The problem is that Round(balance1/days) + Round(balance2/days)  not = round(balance of all broker/days). Any idea how to solve it?